# Inject callback from a class method defined in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, callback

I want to mimic what AR does with `after_save ..., if: -> { bar? }` but I don't understand how I can change context to set `self` to the object.

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def add_callback(options)
      foo = options.fetch(:foo)

      the_real_callback = -> do
        puts foo.call(self).inspect
      end

      before_save(the_real_callback)
    end
  end
end

class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule

  add_callback foo: ->(instance) { instance.bar }

  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

o = MyClass.new
o.save
# displays "bar"
```

I want to replace `add_callback foo: ->(instance) { instance.bar }` with `add_callback foo -> { bar }`

Comment: instance_exec is the key

Comment: Indeed, posted the new below

Comment: don;t understand, did you answer your question?

Comment: yes (posted the new *code* below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @apneadiving, code is now :

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def add_callback(options)
      foo = options.fetch(:foo)

      the_real_callback = -> do
        puts instance_exec(&foo)
      end

      before_save(the_real_callback)
    end
  end
end

class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule

  add_callback foo: -> { bar }

  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

o = MyClass.new
o.save
# displays "bar"
```